# How to get inner html text of sibling element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Why doesn't this print out the text of the span, "Apple "?

```
<label class="search-recipe-chkbox fruitLabel">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox check-box-mob-filters check-box-desktop" id="12DSKT" name="Apple" value="12">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  <span class="ingredient-label">Apple <span class="recipe-count" id="12numDSKT">(1)</span></span>
</label>
```

```
for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
  if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    console.log($(checkbox.id).siblings('.ingredient-label').text());
  }
}
```

`checkboxes` is just all the checkboxes (input) in the form and given that Apple is checked.

Thank you

Comment: Did you defined checkboxes?  It isn't visible in the code.

Comment: Basicly the selector in `console.log`  lacks `#`, jQuery tries to find tags like `<12DSKT>`. Remove `.id`, and your code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `checkbox.id` - in the `console.log`

It needs to have a `#` in the front:

```
for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
  if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    console.log($('#'+checkbox.id).siblings('.ingredient-label').text()); // like this
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Here's a better solution as told by Teemu. Only `checkbox` also works:

```
for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
  if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    console.log($(checkbox).siblings('.ingredient-label').text()); // like this
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to make a DOM traversing trip when you already have a reference to the element?

Comment: If there's only one checkbox as in the question's html, then there's no need of the `for` loop for sure.

Comment: Yep, but I was talking about fetching an element based on the id when you already have a reference to that element in the loop (`checkbox`).

Comment: Ok. I don't quite know if only (`checkbox`) instead of (`'#'+checkbox.id`) works. Won't that return the whole checkbox element?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons that this could occur, however here is my solution to your problem.

```
for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    var val = checkbox.parentElement.querySelector('.ingredient-label').textContent;
    console.log(val);       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use - console.log($("[id]").siblings('.ingredient-label').text());